# Start a download immediately in the browser, instead of filling up with createObjectUrl?

Tags: angular, download, angular9

I am creating an Angular 9 web component with a .NET Core API, and I am currently trying to figure out, what the best approach to starting a download immediately upon clicking is. I would like the browser download (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> is the usual combo) to trigger, instead of showing a download dialog. Bear in mind, the request has to be authorized, meaning I need to provide a JWT token in the request or, preferably, in the Authorization header. Here are my two approaches:

### Approach 1

```
const downloadUrl = 'https://download.com/?selectedFiles=....&token=....';

const downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
downloadLink.href = downloadUrl;
downloadLink.setAttribute('download', 'download');
document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
downloadLink.click();
```

This will trigger a download immediately, because going to the URL in the browser (GET) returns an `application/octet-stream` from my .NET application. However, this is quite bad, as I need to provide the selected files AND the auth token in the URL. An URL has a maximum length, so if the user selected 10000 files, it would probably throw them an error. Not acceptable.

### Approach 2

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Bearer ....');
const downloadUrl = 'https://download.com/?selectedFiles=....';

this.http.get(downloadUrl, { headers, responseType: 'blob' as 'json' }).subscribe(
    (response: any) => {
        const dataType = response.type;
        const binaryData = [];
        binaryData.push(response);
        const downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
        downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(binaryData, { type: dataType }));
        downloadLink.setAttribute('download', 'download');
        document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
        downloadLink.click();
    }
);
```

This approach is better, and can be changed to a POST request, however, it doesn't do anything visually, because it's waiting for the `downloadLink.href` to fill up with the blob data. In this case, I would probably have to make some UI to show a download dialog with progress.

### Question

Are there any other approaches worth knowing? A combination of the two would be nice, where I can send a POST request that starts the download immediately.